# knockout mapping from JS with extra proeprties

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have this jSON structure.

```
{
"customer": {
    "idcustomer": 2,
    "name": "test_2",
    "vat": "test_vat_2",
    "obs": "obs_2",
    "deleted": 0
},
"addresses": [
    {
        "idaddress": 9,
        "street": "street_2_9",
        "number": "number_2_9",
        "country": "country_2_9",
        "default": true,
        "label": "labe_2_9",
        "deleted": 0
    },
    {
        "idaddress": 10,
        "street": "1",
        "number": "number_2_9",
        "country": "country_2_10",
        "default": false,
        "label": "label_2_10",
        "deleted": 0
    }
],
"contacts": []
```

}

With knockout mapping plugin I am able to generate a knockout observable object. However, when trying to add extra properties to the object using the mapping parameter I find some issues. The goal is to add "SelectedAddress" to the main object and in each address a "defaultLabel" observabale.

Currently i have this mapping structure to add the property to the address children:

```
var mapping = {

'addresses': {
    create: function (options) {
        return (new (function () {
            this.defaultLabel= ko.computed(function () {
                return (this.default() == 0) ? "" : this.label();
                }, this);
            ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
        })());
    }
},
```

}

and this to add the "SelectedAddress" to the main JSON:

```
create: function (options) {
        return new function () {

            var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
            // Direccion
            model.direccionSeleccionada = ko.observable();
            model.getDireccion = ko.computed({
                read: function() {
                    if (model.direccionSeleccionada() != null) {
                        return model.direccionSeleccionada();
                    } else {
                        return [{
                                idaddress: -1,
                                street : '',
                                number: '',
                                country: '',
                                default: '',
                                label: '',
                                deleted: '',
                        }];
                    }
                },
                write: function(value) {
                    self.direccionSeleccionada(value);
                },
                owner: self
            });
        }
    }
```

I can not find a way to have them both

Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just for someone; Just as simple as when generatint he mapping of "addresses", add inside another mapping for it.

```
var mapping = {
create: function (options) {
    return new function () {
        var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {
            'adresses': {
                create: function (options) {
                    return (new(function () {
                        this.labelDefault= ko.computed(function () {
                            return (this.default() == 0) ? "" : this.label();
                        }, this);
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
                    })( /* call the ctor here */ ));
                }
            },
        }, this);

        model.direccionSeleccionada = ko.observable();
        model.getDireccion = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                if (model.selectedAddress() != null) {
                    return model.selectedAddress();
                } else {
                    return [{
                        idaddress: -1,
                        street: '',
                        number: '',
                        country: '',
                        default: '',
                        label: '',
                        deleted: ''
                    }];
                }
            },
            write: function (value) {
                self.selectedAddress(value);
            },
            owner: self
        });
    }
}
```

}

Thank you!